# React and Redux HTTP Header Authorization

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, redux-thunk, react-router-redux

I'm trying to setup a React authentication with my API backend. The API backend uses an email and password, and also creates a token with every new user. All of these are provided via straight JSON, not JWT, so I'm using the [Auth0 tut](https://auth0.com/blog/secure-your-react-and-redux-app-with-jwt-authentication/) and this [Stack q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582213/login-api-request-using-react-and-redux) as a starting place.

My first goal is to do a simple login and redirect. I got the action/reducer hooked up and I'm now making the API calls. I'm using a basic auth call and convert it to a 64 bit character and send via the header. Those are tested and work via Postman.

When I do this current React setup, it gets to **"Fetching"** in the console, but never **"I'm here."**, and the page simply reloads. I'm not sure where to fix this and get it it authorize and redirect. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

**HomePage.js (container)**

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
 }

 render() {
  const { dispatch, isAuthenticated } = this.props;
 return (
   <div>
     < HomeHeader onLogin={this.props.onLogin} />
   </div>
  );
 }
}

 function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { loginResponse: state.loginResponse };
 }

 function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
 return {
   onLogin: (creds) => dispatch(loginUser(creds)),
 };
}

export default connect(
mapStateToProps,
mapDispatchToProps
)(HomePage);
```

**AuthorizationActions.js (actions)**

```
function requestLogin(creds) {
 return {
  type: types.LOGIN_REQUEST,
  isFetching: true,
  isAuthenticated: false,
  creds
 }
}
function receiveLogin(user) {
 return {
  type: types.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  isFetching: false,
  isAuthenticated: true,
  id_token: user.id_token
 }
}

export function loginUser(creds) {
 **console.log("Fetching");**
 const hash = new   Buffer(`${creds.username}:${creds.password}`).toString('base64')

return fetch('http://api.xxx.dev/sessions', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ${hash}'
  },
 })
  .then(response => {
    **console.log("I'm here");**
    if(response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300){
      console.log("Response; ", response);
      // Dispatch the success action
      dispatch(receiveLogin(user));
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', user.id_token);
    } else {
      const error = new Error(response.statusText);
      error.response = response;
      dispatch(loginError(user.message))
      throw error;
    }
  })
  .catch(error => { console.log('Request Failed: ', error);});
 }
```

**AuthorizationReducer.js (Reducer)**

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import Immutable from 'immutable';

const initialState = new Immutable.Map({
 username: '',
 password: '',
 isLoggingIn: false,
 isLoggedIn: false,
 isFetching: false,
 error: null,
 isAuthenticated: localStorage.getItem('id_token') ? true : false
});

function authenticationReducer(state = initialState, action) {
 switch ( action.type ) {
 case 'LOGIN_REQUEST':
  return { ...state,
      isFetching: true,
      isAuthenticated: false,
      user: action.creds
  }
 case 'LOGIN_SUCCESS':
  return {
    ...state,
    browserHistory: browserHistory.push('/dashboard')
  }
 case 'LOGIN_FAILURE':
  return alert('Crap, there are login failures');
 default:
  return state;
 }
}
export default authenticationReducer;
```

**configureStore.js (Store)**

```
const middleware = applyMiddleware(
  thunk,
  apiMiddleware,
  global.window ? logger : store => next => action => next( action )
);
const store = createStore( reducers, initialState, compose(middleware,    window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f  ))
```

**AuhorizeLogin.js Component**

```
 constructor(props, context) {
  super(props, context);
  this.state = {};
  this._login = this._login.bind(this);
 }

 _login(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  const email = this.refs.email;
  const password = this.refs.password;
  const creds = { email: email.value.trim(), password: password.value.trim() };
  this.props.onLoginClick(creds);
```

}

**HomeHeader.js Component**

```
 `_handleChange(eventKey) { < AuthorizeLogin onLoginClick={this.props.onLogin}/>); `
```

**HomePage.js Container**

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
}
render() {
 const { dispatch, isAuthenticated } = this.props;
 return (
 ...
 < HomeHeader onLogin={this.props.onLogin} />
 ...
 )
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {

return {
 loginResponse: state.loginResponse,
 };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
 return {
  onLogin: (creds) => dispatch(loginUser(creds)),
 };
}

export default connect(
 mapStateToProps,
 mapDispatchToProps
 )(HomePage);
```

Comment: You mentioned that the page reloads; are you perhaps using a `form` tag and forgot to `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: I added it in the onClick function in the component. Do I need to add it to my actions or somewhere in the reducers if they call another action?

Comment: Can you show that code? I think the problem is likely in your `HomeHeader` component.

Comment: I updated the code above. It should be firing "dispatch(receiveLogin(user));"  in LoginUser as it receives the success, and then redirect.

Comment: There is too much code here for an SO post. I still can't see all your code and I suspect most of what you posted isn't even relevant to your problem. And with the `HomeHeader` component, I'm not even sure what I'm looking at; some missing? Try creating a minimal reproducible scenario or tackling this question outside SO.

Answer (score 3):

Try with `return fetch('http://api.xxx.dev/sessions'...` .
Not tested but, it should get you to "I'm here".
Eventually, wrap the arrow function {}

Comment: Tried this one. Good catch. Now getting this error: (program):1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

Comment: I suggest some reading on this going forward:[Async Actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html)