# Failed prop type: The prop `actions` is marked as required in `Testing`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am creating a simple login form using React and Redux. My `app.js` is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Input from 'react-toolbox/lib/input';
import {Button, IconButton} from 'react-toolbox/lib/button';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import * as loginAction from '../actions/loginAction';

class Testing extends React.Component {
    onLoginFormSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.actions.Testing(this.state.username, this.state.password);
    }
    handleChange(name, value){
        let state = this.state;
        state[name] = value;
        this.setState({state});
        console.log(name); // cannot read property of null
        console.log(value); // cannot read property of null
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <div>
                <form name="Login" onSubmit={(e) => this.onLoginFormSubmit(e)}>
                    <Input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Email Id"  tabIndex="1" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'username')} />
                    <Input name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" type="password" tabIndex="2" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'password')} />                  <Button type="submit" className="m-t-20 blue-btn" label="Sign in" tabIndex="3" /> 
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
Testing.propTypes = {
  loginAction: PropTypes.object.isRequired,

};
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    loginResponse: state.loginResponse
  };
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(loginAction, dispatch)
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Testing);
```

loginAction.js file is:

```
export function loginError(error){
  return  { error, type: LOGIN_FAILED };
}

export function loginSuccess(response){
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ response, type: LOGIN_SUCCESS});
  };
}

export function loginRequest(username, password){
  const user = {username: username, password: password};
  return { user, type: LOGIN_ATTEMPT };
}


export function login(username, password) {
  console.log("User Data: ", username, password);
    return dispatch =>
    fetch('url', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: username,
        password: password
      }),
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log("I'm here");
      if(response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300){
        console.log("Response; ", response);
        dispatch(loginSuccess(response));
      } else {
        const error = new Error(response.statusText);
        error.response = response;
        dispatch(loginError());
        throw error;
      }
    })
    .catch(error => { console.log('Request Failed: ', error);});
  }
```

And loginReducer.js file is:

```
import {
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_FAILED,
  LOGIN_ATTEMPT
} from '../actions/loginAction';
import Immutable from 'immutable';

const initialState = new Immutable.Map({
  username: '',
  password: '',
  isLoggingIn: false,
  isLoggedIn: false,
  error: null
});

export default function user(state = initialState, action){
  switch (action.type){
    case LOGIN_ATTEMPT:
      console.log("LOGIN_ATTEMPT: ",action.user);
      return state.merge({
        isLoggingIn: true,
        isLoggedIn: false,
        username: action.user.username,
        password: action.user.password
      });

    case LOGIN_FAILED:
      console.log("LOGIN_FAILED: ");
      return state.merge({
        error: action.error,
        isLoggingIn: false,
        isLoggedIn: false
      });

    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      console.log("LOGIN_SUCCESS: ",action);
      return state.merge({
        error: null,
        isLoggingIn: false,
        isLoggedIn: true
      })
      break;

    default:
      return state;

  }
}
```

When running the page I am getting this error: Failed prop type: The prop `actions` is marked as required in `Testing`, but its value is `undefined`. Also `handleChange` method is throwing following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'username' of null`.

**Update:** My store.js code is:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import user from '../reducers/loginReducer';

const store = createStore(
  user,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
var routes =(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Main}>
        <Route path="/testing" component={Testing}>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
);
```

<sub>I don't want to use redux-form for now.</sub>

Comment: can you post the code that use and render `<Testing />`?

Comment: @Sag1v updated the code

Comment: i've updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `handleChange` should  get only an event as a parameter.
`handleChange(e)` this event is attached to the target element, so you can access its values via `e.target.value`;
With that said, do not `bind` the handlers in the `render` function. do it in the `constructor` as it will create a new instance of the `handler` on each `render` call. bad for performance.
As for the `redux` flow, you should use `connect`.
`export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Testing)`.
**EDIT**
After another look at your code, beside the fact that you didn't use `connect` to connect the component to `redux`, you are mapping a wrong object to `mapDispatchToProps`.
In this code you are using `loginAction`:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(loginAction, dispatch)
  }
}
```

But you never imported it, you used a name import:
`import { loginSuccess, loginRequest, login } from '../actions/loginAction';`
One possible way to import everything and pass it to `mapDispatchToProps` is this:
`import * as loginAction from '../actions/loginAction';`
Another mistake you made is naming this object with different name on `propTypes`, you named it `actions` and not  `loginAction`

```
Testing.propTypes = {
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired,

};
```

You will need the same name:

```
Testing.propTypes = {
  loginAction: PropTypes.object.isRequired,

};
```

And again don't forget to `connect`!!

Comment: When using connect it return blank page without any error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to connect your component to redux.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

 // your code

 export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Testing)
```

Don't forget to remove `export default` from before your class as well.

Edit: Please use [`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) if you're planning on modifying the local state of a component.

Comment: when using this blank page returns without any error in browser console.